# Is there a public API for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, api

I was just trying to find out if there was a public API for the Stack Overflow site. I want to know so that I could maybe use it for whatever it would let me use it for (like web-service or non browser application that can access Stack Overflow). I have a few (specific) ideas but I don't want anybody to get the jump on me before I have a chance to implement one of them ;). I know that is a little silly since there are a limited number of things that such a thing could be used for. It's not about $$ or copyright* or anything like that; I just want to do it my way first if possible. Anyhow I tried googling this and you can imagine how many results you get for "StackOverflow public api".

Comment: there are browser add-ons so there must be an api...

Comment: Ok so where can I find documentation for it? Just because there is an API does not mean that it is "public". Of course an API exists, i was just wondering if it was accessible and open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an API available.

You can read about the API, develop and submit your own Apps over on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) which is linked in the footer of each site.

[Here is a link to the API Documentaion](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I wanted to know. Too bad it's read-only though. It would be awesome to have the full blown StackOverflow in my pocket. However I suppose that might make getting the ads fairly complicated for both the users (of the API) and StackOverflow. So then it couldn't be a free api. Devs would need to pay for part of it in that case. Hows that for an idea?

Comment: Yeah the link is there. Guess I missed it. Sorry.

Comment: @ettey, a paid write access API could be a good idea.

Comment: Is there an R package for interfacing the API from within R?