# Is there an API for stackoverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a public API for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74664/is-there-a-public-api-for-stack-overflow)

Hey, I was wondering if there is an API for Stackoverflow? I have seen a few "hints" at one...but I would like to stop beating 'round the bush looking for one. Any *direct* links would be awesomely helpful.

Thanks.

```
note: If the API doesn't use PHP, forget about it.
```

Comment: There's a million questions that answer your question over there in the Related sidebar ------>

Comment: @Josh Caswell Yes, there are...but none of them answer it. I needed a direct link...all of them beat around the bush. I have it answered now.

Comment: Note: If you can't use the search function first, forget about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the FAQ on Stack Apps: https://stackapps.com/faq

I've never used it, but I'm nearly certain PHP can consume it.

(Note that it is currently a read-only API.)

Comment: May I suggest: [a search of 'php' and 'api'](http://stackapps.com/search?q=api+php) at [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: Thanks David, squillman. Like I said, I looked around, couldn't find much. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: squillman, I will accept your answer. Thanks for help out.

Comment: @php: I highly recommend the very capable [stack.PHP](http://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php-now-with-v1-1-support) API wrapper. **Disclaimer:** I'm one of the authors.

Comment: Are there any R packages for interfacing this API?